# Adding time using the Datetime Library

Tags: datetime, robotframework

I have setup a test case to where I record to days date and time and when I try to add time to it I receive this message

`ValueError: time data '0426-20-23 10:13:00.000000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'`

I need it to be in this format: `result_format=%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M %p`

Here is my test case:

Thank you for any assistance!

```
Test Case Time
    ${CurrentDate}=  Get Current Date  result_format=%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M %p
    Log to Console  ${CurrentDate}
    ${newdatetime}=  Add Time To Date  ${CurrentDate}  30 minutes
    Log to console  ${newdatetime}
```

I was expecting it to add 30 minutes to the time.

Comment: `Add Time To Date` expects "Time Format" which is different from "Date Format" used in `Get Current Date`.  You are now passing custom "Date Format" to a keyword that does not support it.  .  Easier approach would be to get current date as epoch  - do any/all calculations with epoch and only format to actual human readable date if/when needed.